# How can I prevent or launch an action if an unauthorized process create/modify a file to a specific directory?

Tags: windows, security

Is it possible to prevent a file from being written or modified in a specific folder if the username and the process name is different than a specific value ?

If not, is it possible to trigger an action if a specific event ID is containing 2 details such as username and process fullpath is equals to something ?

### Context

A windows service that I run is running under a service account with interactive logon that is needed for debugging purpose and I would like to ensure that files created in a specific directory are indeed written by the proper process or if not, that an alert is launched by the server.

### What I have tested so far

1. FSRM (file system resource manager) and it is totally blocking
   all files created in a directory or just monitoring file creation (not modification).
2. Wrote a C# program and used System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to monitor a directory but if a creation/modification is made, the process is not provided by FileSystemEventArgs.

### What I will test soon...

Activating file auditing on this directory and writing a C# program that is monitoring a specific event ID and trigger when the content is containing an unauthorized username and process name.

Otherwise, all suggestions are welcomed... Thank you.